# Host an ActiveX control with multiple Interfaces in WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, activex

I have to use a third-party ActiveX control in my WinForms application. The problem is that the computers, my application will run on, could have any version of the control. The first one had IControl1 interface, successive versions of the library have IControl2, IControl3 and so on, upto IControl6 interface.

The problem I'm running into is that if I use the latest version of the control in Visual Studio and place it on the form, Visual Studio generates the complete class information for all classes, however, at runtime if the computer had a older version of the control then my application throws a run-time exception. On the other hand, if I add the earliest version in Visual Studio, then it works all the time, however, it doesn't generate interface info for the later version. Which are needed in certain cases.

How do I generate interface info (typelibrary) for the latest version while still be able to make the program work if the computer only has first version? I don't want to generate a typelibrary for each version as that will increase the size of the application and create too much complexity.

Comment: Generally an application that uses an ActiveX also deploys it.  Are you able to deploy a particular version even if it is side-by-side with other versions?  As for the typelibrary, you'll probably find it's embedded either in the .ocx or is a stand-alone .tlb file next to it so _generating_ is not required.

Comment: Unfortunately, due to licensing issue we can't redistribute the control, we have to use the one already installed. In case there isn't any installed, then we just display an error message to the user.

Comment: OK.  You could perhaps instantiate one dynamically (since you won't know what's there at _design time_) from a progid/classid (after enumerating the registry).  Then you could just query for `IControl1`; `IControlxx` or use `dynamic`

Comment: What would be the minimum version of the control you wish to target? In other words is there some feature you need access to? e.g. `IControl2`   Otherwise you could just refer to `IControl1` everywhere in your code and that would work irrespective of which control is installed. All you need to do is instantiate the installed version dynamically

Comment: The minimum I want to target is IControl2, however, there are certain features that I want to enable in the UI if a later version is present. How do I instantiate a control dynamically? Do I need a typelibrary for that?

Comment: A TL for your case is only required to generate classes which you don't want, a TL is not required to instantiate a control. You want dynamic.  http://mike-ward.net/2006/11/02/testing-activex-controls-in-c/

Comment: Actually, I want to instantiate a control. Then call a few properties (4-5), need to call a few methods (about 8) and also register for events (3). So I was thinking if I can avoid the headache of TL, and just load the control dynamically and invoke properties etc, that would be great. How do I do the last part? Also, I have to use .NET 2.0, so probably can't use dynamic?